# How to Get Child name from Expression?

Tags: c#, expression-trees

```
Expression<Func<Tab, object>> includeExpressions = x => x.Columns;
```

With these lines of code

```
var expression = (MemberExpression)includeExpressions.Body;
string PropertyName = expression.Member.Name;
```

I am getting Property Name as "Columns". But here I have another Expression

```
Expression<Func<Tab, object>> includeExpressions = x => x.Columns.Select(y=>y.Options);
```

I want to get name as Columns.Options. Can anybody have idea about this ?
I mean I want to get for child property as well.

Comment: Do you *just* want to support the pattern `c.<thing>.Select(y => y.<thing>)`, or do you want to pick out names more generally from other patterns?

Comment: There could be any patterns

Comment: Well that's impossible in the general case. If you do `x.Columns.Furble(y => y.Options)`, how do you know that the method `Furble` goes through each column and calls its delegate on them? The implementation of `Furble` could be `selector(new Column())`

Comment: Actually i have Classes and classed have navigation properties . So basically i need the name of the property through expression or if there is another way then it would help me too. like Tabs is a class which is navigating to Columns class as one to Many Relation. same as Column class navigating to Option Class

Comment: Like EF's `Include()`? That just supports `Select` IIRC, not "any patterns"

Comment: Yes . I want to implement Include method in my Repository Pattern . and I don't want to write static names for proprieties  **public IQueryable<TEntity> Include(Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> includeExpressions)
        {
            //var expression = (MemberExpression)includeExpressions.Body;
            //string PropertyName = expression.Member.Name;
            return dbSet.Include(includeExpressions).AsQueryable<TEntity>();
        }.**

Comment: I am calling this method as 
            **var tabsDetail = await unitOfWork.TabRepository
                .Include(x=>x.Columns.Select(y=>y.Options))
                .Include(x => x.Columns.Select(y => y.Options))
                .ToListAsync();**

Comment: And also i dont want to use **ThenInclude**

Comment: I have no idea what `ThenInclude` is

Comment: If you **ONLY** want to support `Select`, that makes life a bit easier

Comment: Yes That i can do . I can restrict with **Select** Only

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

It uses an `ExpressionVisitor` to walk the expression, and try to follow member accesses (`parent.Child`). It knows about the "Select" method, and that the lambda is called once for each item in the input.

We end up with a set of parent -> child relationships: from `x` you access `x.Columns`, from `x.Columns` you call `Select`, from the `Select` you map the result of `x.Columns` onto the `y` parameter, from the `y` parameter you call `y.Options`, etc. We store these in a dictionary as a parent/child pair (along with the name, if it was a member access).

We then recursively walk the dictionary starting from the `includeExpressions`, and create chains of parent/child accesses.

```
public class PropertyAccessVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    public Dictionary<Expression, List<(Expression child, string name)>> ParentsToChildren { get; } = new Dictionary<Expression, List<(Expression child, string name)>>();

    protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
    {
        // If it's a call to Select, then we know that it calls its lambda on each of the items in its input
        if (node.Method.Name == "Select" && node.Method.DeclaringType == typeof(Enumerable))
        {
            Add(node.Arguments[0], node.Arguments[1], null);
        }

        return base.VisitMethodCall(node);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitLambda<T>(Expression<T> node)
    {
        foreach (var parameter in node.Parameters)
        {
            Add(node, parameter, null);
        }

        return base.VisitLambda(node);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        Add(node.Expression, node, node.Member.Name);
        return base.VisitMember(node);
    }

    private void Add(Expression parent, Expression child, string name)
    {
        if (!ParentsToChildren.TryGetValue(parent, out var children))
        {
            children = new List<(Expression child, string name)>();
            ParentsToChildren[parent] = children;
        }
        children.Add((child, name));
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    Expression<Func<Tab, object>> includeExpressions = x => x.Columns.Select(y => y.Options);
    var visitor = new PropertyAccessVisitor();
    visitor.Visit(includeExpressions);

    var results = new List<string>();
    var stack = new Stack<(Expression expression, string path)>();
    stack.Push((includeExpressions, null));
    while (stack.Count > 0)
    {
        var (expression, path) = stack.Pop();
        if (visitor.ParentsToChildren.TryGetValue(expression, out var children))
        {
            foreach (var child in children)
            {
                stack.Push((child.child, child.name == null ? path : $"{path}.{child.name}"));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            results.Add(path);
        }
    }
}
```